# Gstreamer switch video and play the new one from the timestamp of Previous video

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I use gstreamer on VS2017 MFC.
I'm trying to play one video at a time, and when I switch another video, player can play the new one start from the position(timestamp) of previous video.
I use Seek, but it need some delay time to set pipeline's "current_state"==PLAYING, and it will show the first frame of this video at the delay time.
I don't want to see that!!!

Comment: I set video2 as "suburi" to do that, but it can't set two or more suburi.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.